# Mysql criteria from two tables with optional second criteria

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables :

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `job_id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `contact_name` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `phone` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `title` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `is_approve` TINYINT(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `is_default_contact` TINYINT(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `is_original_contact` TINYINT(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `signer` TINYINT(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=1
;

CREATE TABLE `table2` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `contact_id` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `signature_owner` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `pl_id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `sign_date` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `authorization_sign_date` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `sign_tag_file_name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `authorization_file_name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `signature_note` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `authorization_signature_note` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `signature_owner_email` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=1
;

where table1.id = table2.contact.id
```

And i need to select all records from `table1` based on `job_id` and to populate all data from `table2` if we have the same `ids` with our desired `pl_id`.

```
Example:
In table1 are 3 records with job_id=1:
record1
record2
record3
In table2 is only record2 with pl_id=1
```

So the result must be

```
record1 + empty feilds from table2
record2 + pupulated all the fields from table2
record3 + empty feilds from table2
```

To do that i tried with this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table2 s
LEFT JOIN table1 p ON s.contact_id=p.id
WHERE p.job_id=1605 and s.pl_id=5150
```

but it returns only `record2`

Answer (score 0):

You are making left join on wrong table. You want table1 record having p_id and do left join on table2

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 p
LEFT JOIN table2 s ON s.contact_id=p.id
WHERE p.job_id=1605
```

Comment: The result is the same

Comment: @ВладимирГичев try now

Answer (score 0):

You just need to give left join, due to your condition result might be modified,

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 p
LEFT JOIN table2 s ON s.contact_id=p.id
```